# DLL won't copy in a post-build event

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm testing out how to work with DLL's in C++. For this I'm following a [Microsoft walk-through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019). Everything is working as it should, but I'm stuck at ["To copy the DLL in a post-build event"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019#to-copy-the-dll-in-a-post-build-event).

This is what I have put in: [image]

When I build the program, everything looks fine but there is no file copied.[image]

and when I run the program I get this error:[image]

Anyone know a solution to my problem?

Comment: Was MathLibrary.dll copied to MathClient\Debug?

Comment: Also, did you put this in a post-build event for MathLibrary or MathClient? If the first, did you try rebuilding MathLibrary?

Comment: Side suggestion - ensure that 'MathClient' is configured to depend on 'MathLibrary'.

Comment: Nice stump-the-chumps question, hawk-eyes needed.  Note the titlebar of the window in the screenshot, "Description".  You edited the description of the build event, that's not correct.  Edit the Command instead.  Phil's comment only applies if you have MathLibrary in the same solution.  Which is a good idea, but you wouldn't have to do this at all if that was the case.  $(IntDir) is iffy, but you'll get away with it in a 32-bit build.

Comment: @Botje negative, MathLibrary.dll is not present in MathClient/Debug. I put the post-build event in the MathClient

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I followed ever step on the Mircosoft walk-through. Do I need to add anything else to my MathLibrary or MathClient?

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not completly sure what you mean. Both MathLibrary and MathClient have there own solution. The Microsoft walk-through says That I have to use ..\..\ to get the the other solution, however this is not working. ..\..\. If I do this it points to the installation directory.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm blind it seems. I looked at the post-event again and I saw what you meant. I moved the command from "description" to "Command Line". I thank your Hawk-eyes

Comment: wes - @HansPassant (unsurprisingly!) spotted the issue - take what you've entered in the "Description" box and move it to the "Command Line" box.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant pointed out that I put the command in the description box of Post-Build event property. Everything is working as it should now.